# mailR: sending email to server failed

Tags: r, email

I am trying to send an email using the mailR package. I can do this at home, from my personal computer and internet, but not at work, where we have company installed and managed firewall, antivirus, etc. When I try, I get a 
long error message, finishing with:

> Error: EmailException (Java): Sending the email to the following server failed : smtp.gmail.com:465

I will paste the complete error message at the bottom of this question.

The code I am using is the following:

```
send.mail(from="MyEmail@gmail.com",
          to="MyOtherEmail@hotmail.com",
          subject="Test Email",
          body="Test body",
          html=T,
          smtp=list(host.name = "smtp.gmail.com",
                    port = 465, #587,
                    user.name = "MyEmail@gmail.com",
                    passwd = "xxxx",
                    ssl=T), #tls = T),
          authenticate=T,
          debug=T)
```

After reading a few similar questions, I have tried changing the port to 587, simultaneously with `tls=T` instead of `ssl=T`. I already have less-secure apps enabled on my google account, and I do not have ''two factor' authentification enabled, but I don't think the problem is related to my google account, as the code works from home. I do not have the option of turning antivirus software off, this is company controlled and is not possible for me. 
Using the `Debug` option in `send.mail`, the final line, where I guess the problem comes up was:

> DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "smtp.gmail.com", port 465, isSSL false

Does anybody have any ideas about how I can get an email notification from R to let me know that my script has finished running and what the outcome was, despite my firewall and antivirus restrictions? I am not fussy about using the `mailR` package - I also tried `mail` as suggested in this post:

[sending mail from R (mailR)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29450427/sending-mail-from-r-mailr)

with the following code:

```
sendmail("MyEmail@gmail.com", "mail of R", "Testing!")
```

but with this I got the following error message:

```
Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(con, "r") :
cannot open URL 'http://rmail.linhi.de/rmail.php?Email=MyEmail@gmail.com&Passwort=rmail&Betreff=mail<of<R&Nachricht=Testing!': HTTP status was '404 Not Found'

Here is the full Debug result and error message I get using send.mail:
>DEBUG: JavaMail version 1.5.2
DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.providers
DEBUG: Tables of loaded providers
DEBUG: Providers Listed By Class Name: {com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Oracle], com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle], com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Oracle], com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3s,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore,Oracle], com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Oracle], com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Oracle]}
DEBUG: Providers Listed By Protocol: {imaps=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Oracle], imap=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Oracle], smtps=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Oracle], pop3=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Oracle], pop3s=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3s,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore,Oracle], smtp=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle]}
DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.address.map
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle]
DEBUG SMTP: need username and password for authentication
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "smtp.gmail.com", port 465, isSSL false
org.apache.commons.mail.EmailException: Sending the email to the following server failed : smtp.gmail.com:465
    at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.sendMimeMessage(Email.java:1410)
    at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.send(Email.java:1437)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at RJavaTools.invokeMethod(RJavaTools.java:386)
Caused by: com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: smtp.gmail.com, 465; timeout 60000;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:2053)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:697)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:386)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:245)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:194)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:253)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
    at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.sendMimeMessage(Email.java:1400)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:310)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:215)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:2019)
    ... 13 more
```